# OCaml list types behavior

Tags: list, types, ocaml, static-typing

Following the chapter of Real World OCaml on [error handling](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/error-handling.html), it is permissible to construct a list as such:

```
utop # [ Ok 3; Error "abject failure"; Ok 4] ;;                           
- : (int, string) Result.t list = [Ok 3; Error "object failure"; Ok 4]
```

I have read in this text and in others, however, that "all elements of a list must be of the same type."

Then what exactly is the type `(int, string) Result.t`? As far as I can tell, this is permissible because both `Ok` and `Error` are of the same type `Result.t`. The tuple-like notation of `(int, string)`, however, is confusing to me, and if the above is acceptable, why isn't something like this fine as well:

```
utop # [ Ok 3; Error "abject failure"; Ok "asdf"] ;;              
325 Error: This expression has type string but an expression was expected of type
             int
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Result.t` is a parameterized type. That is, it takes two types and forms them into a new type. This is the same as the way that `list` takes one type and forms it into a new type.

The type of `[3; 4; 5]` is `int list`. That is, it's a list whose elements are ints.

In the same way, the type `(int, string) Result.t` is a result whose good values are given by ints and whose errors are given by strings.

For a given choice of types for a and b, values like `Ok a` and `Error b` are indeed the same type. This is a little bit like the way that `Some 3` and `None` are the same type.

Note that `Result.t` only takes *two* types, one for the good results and one for the errors. The problem with your last example is that you're using two different types for your good results.

Comment: Ah, and that explains why declaring just `Ok 3` gives `(int, 'a) Result.t`, since `'a` can be any type. Thanks!